# Toggle class and text in angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a lock and unlock functionality, which in html is represented by

```
<li><a ng:click="lock(selectedUser)"><i class="icon-lock icon"></i>Lock</a></li>
```

and

```
<li><a ng:click="unlock(selectedUser)"><i class="icon-unlock icon"></i>UnLock</a></li>
```

Unlock/Lock is acutally a REST API call

```
$scope.unlock = function(user){
     user.$unlock();
}

$scope.lock = function(user){
     user.$lock();
}
```

How can I toggle between the two states in angular.js? I mean when a lock is performed and is successfull the first option should be hidden while the unlock button should get visible.

```
selectedUser.enabled
```

returns `1` for unlocked and `0` for locked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use one `li`, and set the class with [`ng:class`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass):

**HTML:**

```html
<li>
  <a ng:click="toggleLock(selectedUser)">
    <i class="icon" ng:class="{ 'icon-lock': selectedUser.enabled, 'icon-unlock': ! selectedUser.enabled }"></i>
    {{ selectedUser.enabled && 'Lock' || 'Unlock' }}
  </a>
</li>
```

**Javascript:**

```js
$scope.toggleLock = function (user) {
     user.enabled ? user.$lock() : user.$unlock();
}
```

---

**Update:** Angular 1.1.5 added support for ternary operators, so the above can be re-written as:

```
{{ selectedUser.enabled ? 'Lock' : 'Unlock' }}
```

Comment: @artworkadシ - I changed my answer to reflect your clarified question.

Comment: Thank you that works. Can I change the text "Lock" to "Unlock" the same way?